# How to find apps that start with a specific alphabet? - Android Launcher

Tags: java, android, launcher, package-managers, android-launcher

I'm making a launcher for android with a feature where the user selects an alphabet, then apps starting with that alphabet will be displayed.
I'm having a class that stores name, icon, etc of apps and can successfully display it using Gridiew. But I can't seem to figure out how to display only the selected apps that starts with the selected alphabet.

**MainActivity/Dashboard.java**

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {

DrawerAdapter drawerAdapterObject;
GridView drawerGrid;

class Pac {
    Drawable icon;
    String name;
    String label;
}

Pac[] pacs;
PackageManager pm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    pm = getPackageManager();
    set_pacs();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
    filter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(new PacReciever(), filter);
}

public void set_pacs() {
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    mainIntent.hasExtra("facebok");
    List<ResolveInfo> pacsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    pacs = new Pac[pacsList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < pacsList.size(); i++) {
        pacs[i] = new Pac();
        pacs[i].icon = pacsList.get(i).loadIcon(pm);
        pacs[i].name = pacsList.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
        pacs[i].label = pacsList.get(i).loadLabel(pm).toString();
    }
    new SortApps().exchage_sort(pacs);

    drawerAdapterObject = new DrawerAdapter(this, pacs);
    drawerGrid.setAdapter(drawerAdapterObject);
    drawerGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListner(this, pacs, pm));
}

public class PacReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        set_pacs();
    }
}

public void test(){
    Intent test = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(test);
}
}
```

**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.zyconut.socio.Dashboard">

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimarytrans"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="50dp"/>

</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DrawerAdapter.java**

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
Dashboard.Pac[] pacsForAdapter;

public DrawerAdapter(Context c, Dashboard.Pac pacs[]) {
    mContext = c;
    pacsForAdapter = pacs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pacsForAdapter.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(pacsForAdapter[pos].icon);
    viewHolder.text.setText(pacsForAdapter[pos].label);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**DrawerClickListner.java**

```
public class DrawerClickListner implements OnItemClickListener {

Context mContext;
Dashboard.Pac[] pacsForAdapter;
PackageManager pmForListner;

public DrawerClickListner(Context c, Dashboard.Pac[] pacs, PackageManager pm) {

    mContext = c;
    pacsForAdapter = pacs;
    pmForListner = pm;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

    Intent launchIntent =     pmForListner.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pacsForAdapter[pos].name);
    mContext.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
}
```

**SortApps.java**

```
public class SortApps {
public void exchage_sort(Dashboard.Pac[] pacs){
    int i,j;
    Dashboard.Pac temp;

    for(i = 0; i < pacs.length; i++) {
        for(j = i + 1; j < pacs.length; j++) {
            if(pacs[i].label.compareToIgnoreCase(pacs[j].label) > 0) {
                temp = pacs[i];
                pacs[i] = pacs[j];
                pacs[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**drawer_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_image"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:padding="3dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/icon_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my first post, please do forgive me for any mistakes.

I just need someone to point me to how i can display apps starting with **'A' only**. Rest I may be able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of installed applications using the following snippet.

```
List<String> installedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

    String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    installedApps.add(appName);
}
```

Then you can use this List to filter applications based on starting alphabet.

Comment: um. im a noob. so can you please explain how i can link it to the gridview?

Comment: I showed you how to get the list of application names in a list of strings. All you need to do is add this to your `Pac` array which you pass to your adapter

Comment: i'm passing the class which has the icons and list. so how can i make modifications to the adapter so that if the name starts with a, i can set the app if not skip to the next one or something. really sorry to bother you, i've tried googling 12 hrs straight and couldn't solve my issue. please help. ^_^